# Django REST - как использовать два serializer внутри одного API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Как использовать два serializer внутри одного API?
Столкнулся с проблемой получения общего списка объектов и получения одного объекта.

serializers.py:

```
class SortedItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = ItemSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = SortedItem


class SortedItemIdSerializerBasic(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SortedItem
```

view.py:

```
class SortedItemsAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = SortedItem

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'POST']:
            return SortedItemIdSerializerBasic
        return SortedItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('order')

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {'user': request.user.id, 'order': 100}
        data.update(request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for order, element in enumerate(request.data['sorted']):
            self.model.objects.filter(
                user=request.user, id=element).update(
                order=order
            )
        print(request.data['sorted'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_id=pk, user=request.user)
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

если я добавляю метод get:

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_id=pk, user=request.user)
        return Response(item, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

То по get возвращается весь набор, а не один объект.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте APIViewSet'ы. Перепишите метод получения сериализатора:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ModelListSerializer # Сериализатор для списков
        return ModelDetailSerializer   # Сериализатор для отдельной записи
    return ModelWriteSerializer        # Сериализатор обновления/создания записей
```